# Angular 4 getting values from checkboxes

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-material2

I am new to angular and am stuck at this pretty simple problem. I am getting data from a webservice to show a couple of checkboxes. I need a way to get the value of all of the checkboxes selected by the user. I am using material theme.

```
<span *ngFor="let x of maintainanceTypeList">
    <md-checkbox 
       name="{{x.maintenancetype}}" 
       value="{{x.maintenancetype}}"  
       [formControl]="CreateSocietyForm.controls['checkMaintainanceType']">
         {{x.maintenancetype}}
    </md-checkbox>
</span>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a `change` event to `md-checkbox` and pass the object to a function. Maintain an `array` that keep track of which ones got `checked` and `unchecked` and update the array according to that.

html:

```
<span *ngFor="let x of maintainanceTypeList">
    <md-checkbox 
       name="{{x.maintenancetype}}" 
       value="{{x.maintenancetype}}"
       (change)="change($event, x)">
         {{x.maintenancetype}}
    </md-checkbox>
</span>

<p> Selected value: {{selectedValue | json}} </p>
```

component.ts:

```
export class SelectFormExample {
  selectedValue = [];

  maintainanceTypeList = [
    {maintenancetype: 'Steak'},
    {maintenancetype: 'Pizza'},
    {maintenancetype: 'Tacos'}
  ];

  change(e, type){
    console.log(e.checked);
    console.log(type);
    if(e.checked){
      this.selectedValue.push(type);
    }
    else{
     let updateItem = this.selectedValue.find(this.findIndexToUpdate, type.maintenancetype));

     let index = this.selectedValue.indexOf(updateItem);

     this.selectedValue.splice(index, 1);
    }

  }

  findIndexToUpdate(type) { 
        return type.maintenancetype === this;
    }
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/kJiiYx2IubT7SMTqKBqZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of `e.checked` you can use the following:

Working example

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" (change)="selectBadge($event, badge._id)">
```

**Typescript**

```
selectBadge (e, id) {

 if (e.target.checked) {
   this.product.badges.push(id);
 }  else {
   this.product.badges.splice(this.product.badges.indexOf(id), 1);
 }

}
```

Comment: I will guess you're refering to the other answer to this question. Please edit your answer to include that. In the future consider adding such small additions as comments to the other answer. Bonus: I think you have made an invalid assumption. You are using `<input>` while the other answe is using a `<md-checkbox>`. The events are different for the two types